# Web application install using Installshield LE misses some files when built by msbuild (but not when built in the IDE)

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, installshield, installshield-le

I have a simple web application (MVC/Web API, Dev studio 2013)) where I have used the included Installshield LE for the deployment. I use the primary output to define the target files.

If I build this all in the IDE (Dev Studio), the installation works fine (ie all files are deployed)

However, if I build from the commandline using msbuild (as I want to on our build server) as follows...

```
msbuild myapp.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=SingleImage
```

the install builds ok, but there are files missing in the target folder after the installation is run. All the missing files are references added by nuget..

```
eg Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration etc).
```

Not all of them are missing, for example it does include Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll, but not the other 2 unity related assemblies (ie Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll and Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention.dll).

I have no idea of what else to try. It works fine when built in the IDE, but not with msbuild.

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated